# How can I get VS 2015 RC to build my solution entirely even if nothing has changed in some projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, version

It seems that VS 2015 RC and VS 2013 both seem to skip building the projects that doesn’t have any changes. The problem due to this is, my .dll versions mismatch and I get an exception saying blah.dll with #.##.## version number could not be found. 
I’ve tried getting specific from TFS with options to override files locally, clean, rebuild, delete the bin folder; nothing seems to update the version number for the projects that didn’t have any change. However, if I go to the specified project, add a space or any change, and do the build, it then updates the version number. I don’t want to do that manually for over 50 projects though.
Is there a setting that I would force VS to build everything in the solution regardless of changes or not?

Comment: It looks like your incremental build is badly broken. How did you set up the assembly versioning? Is it through standard TFS template that modifies AssebmlyInfo.cs or do you use some custom mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Add `/target:Rebuild` to the **MSBuild Arguments** in the Build Process (*Process* tab, *Advanced* group).

Comment: While that might work it's a band-aid as it should not be required. Something else is broken.